# Highlight lines in gitgutter sublime textt

Tags: git, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is it possible to highlight new or changed lines in sublime text using GitGutter? I expect to get effect similar to this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvbYt.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently possible. [`GitGutter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GitGutter) creates icons in the gutter (to the left of the line numbers) which are colored according to your color scheme. It does *not* scope the entire line, which IMO is a good thing™. However, if you have an idea for scoping the entire line, you can [open an issue](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/issues) and discuss it with the author.